# A "semi-genetic" definition of addition and multiplication in the field $\operatorname{On}_p$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, finite-fields, fields, nim

Let $+,\cdot$ denote multiplication in $\mathbb{N}_0$. The addition and multiplication in [$\operatorname{On}_p$](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.0962) are denoted $\oplus, \otimes$.

Recursive definition of addition:

$$x \oplus y := ((x+y) \mod (p)) + (\lfloor\frac{x}{p}\rfloor \oplus \lfloor \frac{y}{p}\rfloor )\cdot p$$

This can be expanded to give:

$$x \oplus y := \sum_{i=0}^{\max(r,s)} ((x_i+y_i)\mod(p) )\cdot p^i$$

where $x = \sum_{i=0}^r x_i p^i$, $y = \sum_{i=0}^s y_i p^i$ is the $p$-adic expansion of $x,y$.

(Semi-) Recursive definition of multiplication:

First initialize multiplication table $M[x,y]:=-1$

The function $x \otimes y$ computes in this order (After computation the multiplication table gets updated):

1. The cases $a=0$ or $b=0$, $a=1$ or $b=1$ are defined to be consistent with multiplication rules of $0,1$ in fields.
2. The cases $a\le p-1$ and $b \le p-1$ are defined $\mod (p)$:

   $a\otimes b:= a \cdot b \mod (p)$
3. We first generate a candidate set based on Conway $\operatorname{mex}$ definition:
   $C := \{ 1,2,\cdots,a\cdot b\}-\{((a'\otimes b)\oplus (b' \otimes a) \ominus (a' \otimes b')| a'<a,b'<b\}$

   Usually in $\operatorname{On}_2$ the $\min$ of this set is taken as definition of $a \otimes b$.
   This does however not work, as it happens that it is not distributive.
   To make it distribute I propose the following:

   Once we have chosen an $x$ from the candidate set $C$ for $a \otimes b$, using the distributive law in fields, we can fix some entries in the multiplicaion table $M$. However, it can happen that we get a contradicition to $M$. So we must chose another $x$ from $C$. So I will chose the smalles $x$ in C, which does not contradict the distributive law with the current multiplication table $M$:

$M[a\ominus a',b \ominus b'] = x \ominus M[a,b'] \ominus M[b,a'] \oplus M[a',b'] \forall a'<a,b'<b$

Sorry for not being more precise, but this is an experiment, and I have not figured out everything yet. Yet, the "empirical" results seem promising:

addition: 2 2

$$ \left(\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right) $$

multiplicatin: 2 2

$$ \left(\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right) $$

addition: 2 4
$$ \left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
1 & 0 & 3 & 2 \\
2 & 3 & 0 & 1 \\
3 & 2 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right) $$
multiplicatin: 2 4
$$ \left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & 2 & 3 & 1 \\
0 & 3 & 1 & 2
\end{array}\right) $$

addition: 3 3
$$ \left(\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 2 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right) $$

multiplicatin: 3 3
$$ \left(\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 2 & 1
\end{array}\right) $$

addition: 3 9
$$ \left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr}
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
1 & 2 & 0 & 4 & 5 & 3 & 7 & 8 & 6 \\
2 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 3 & 4 & 8 & 6 & 7 \\
3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
4 & 5 & 3 & 7 & 8 & 6 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
5 & 3 & 4 & 8 & 6 & 7 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
6 & 7 & 8 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
7 & 8 & 6 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 4 & 5 & 3 \\
8 & 6 & 7 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 3 & 4
\end{array}\right) $$

multiplicatin: 3 9
$$ \left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
0 & 2 & 1 & 6 & 8 & 7 & 3 & 5 & 4 \\
0 & 3 & 6 & 2 & 5 & 8 & 1 & 4 & 7 \\
0 & 4 & 8 & 5 & 6 & 1 & 7 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & 5 & 7 & 8 & 1 & 3 & 4 & 6 & 2 \\
0 & 6 & 3 & 1 & 7 & 4 & 2 & 8 & 5 \\
0 & 7 & 5 & 4 & 2 & 6 & 8 & 3 & 1 \\
0 & 8 & 4 & 7 & 3 & 2 & 5 & 1 & 6
\end{array}\right) $$

addition: 5 5
$$ \left(\begin{array}{rrrrr}
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 0 \\
2 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 1 \\
3 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
4 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3
\end{array}\right) $$

multiplicatin: 5 5
$$ \left(\begin{array}{rrrrr}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
0 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 3 \\
0 & 3 & 1 & 4 & 2 \\
0 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1
\end{array}\right) $$

addition: 5 25
$$ \left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr}
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 5 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 10 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 15 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 20 \\
2 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 5 & 6 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 10 & 11 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 15 & 16 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 20 & 21 \\
3 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 8 & 9 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 13 & 14 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 18 & 19 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 23 & 24 & 20 & 21 & 22 \\
4 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 9 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 14 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 19 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 24 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 \\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 5 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 10 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 15 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 20 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 0 \\
7 & 8 & 9 & 5 & 6 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 10 & 11 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 15 & 16 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 20 & 21 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 1 \\
8 & 9 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 13 & 14 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 18 & 19 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 23 & 24 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
9 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 14 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 19 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 24 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 10 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 15 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 20 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 5 \\
12 & 13 & 14 & 10 & 11 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 15 & 16 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 20 & 21 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 5 & 6 \\
13 & 14 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 18 & 19 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 23 & 24 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 8 & 9 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
14 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 19 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 24 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 9 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 \\
16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 15 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 20 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 5 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 10 \\
17 & 18 & 19 & 15 & 16 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 20 & 21 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 5 & 6 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 10 & 11 \\
18 & 19 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 23 & 24 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 8 & 9 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 13 & 14 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
19 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 24 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 9 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 14 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 \\
21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 20 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 5 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 10 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 15 \\
22 & 23 & 24 & 20 & 21 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 5 & 6 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 10 & 11 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 15 & 16 \\
23 & 24 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 8 & 9 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 13 & 14 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 18 & 19 & 15 & 16 & 17 \\
24 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 9 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 14 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 19 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18
\end{array}\right) $$

multiplicatin: 5 25
$$ \left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 \\
0 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 3 & 10 & 12 & 14 & 11 & 13 & 20 & 22 & 24 & 21 & 23 & 5 & 7 & 9 & 6 & 8 & 15 & 17 & 19 & 16 & 18 \\
0 & 3 & 1 & 4 & 2 & 15 & 18 & 16 & 19 & 17 & 5 & 8 & 6 & 9 & 7 & 20 & 23 & 21 & 24 & 22 & 10 & 13 & 11 & 14 & 12 \\
0 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 20 & 24 & 23 & 22 & 21 & 15 & 19 & 18 & 17 & 16 & 10 & 14 & 13 & 12 & 11 & 5 & 9 & 8 & 7 & 6 \\
0 & 5 & 10 & 15 & 20 & 2 & 7 & 12 & 17 & 22 & 4 & 9 & 14 & 19 & 24 & 1 & 6 & 11 & 16 & 21 & 3 & 8 & 13 & 18 & 23 \\
0 & 6 & 12 & 18 & 24 & 7 & 13 & 19 & 20 & 1 & 14 & 15 & 21 & 2 & 8 & 16 & 22 & 3 & 9 & 10 & 23 & 4 & 5 & 11 & 17 \\
0 & 7 & 14 & 16 & 23 & 12 & 19 & 21 & 3 & 5 & 24 & 1 & 8 & 10 & 17 & 6 & 13 & 15 & 22 & 4 & 18 & 20 & 2 & 9 & 11 \\
0 & 8 & 11 & 19 & 22 & 17 & 20 & 3 & 6 & 14 & 9 & 12 & 15 & 23 & 1 & 21 & 4 & 7 & 10 & 18 & 13 & 16 & 24 & 2 & 5 \\
0 & 9 & 13 & 17 & 21 & 22 & 1 & 5 & 14 & 18 & 19 & 23 & 2 & 6 & 10 & 11 & 15 & 24 & 3 & 7 & 8 & 12 & 16 & 20 & 4 \\
0 & 10 & 20 & 5 & 15 & 4 & 14 & 24 & 9 & 19 & 3 & 13 & 23 & 8 & 18 & 2 & 12 & 22 & 7 & 17 & 1 & 11 & 21 & 6 & 16 \\
0 & 11 & 22 & 8 & 19 & 9 & 15 & 1 & 12 & 23 & 13 & 24 & 5 & 16 & 2 & 17 & 3 & 14 & 20 & 6 & 21 & 7 & 18 & 4 & 10 \\
0 & 12 & 24 & 6 & 18 & 14 & 21 & 8 & 15 & 2 & 23 & 5 & 17 & 4 & 11 & 7 & 19 & 1 & 13 & 20 & 16 & 3 & 10 & 22 & 9 \\
0 & 13 & 21 & 9 & 17 & 19 & 2 & 10 & 23 & 6 & 8 & 16 & 4 & 12 & 20 & 22 & 5 & 18 & 1 & 14 & 11 & 24 & 7 & 15 & 3 \\
0 & 14 & 23 & 7 & 16 & 24 & 8 & 17 & 1 & 10 & 18 & 2 & 11 & 20 & 9 & 12 & 21 & 5 & 19 & 3 & 6 & 15 & 4 & 13 & 22 \\
0 & 15 & 5 & 20 & 10 & 1 & 16 & 6 & 21 & 11 & 2 & 17 & 7 & 22 & 12 & 3 & 18 & 8 & 23 & 13 & 4 & 19 & 9 & 24 & 14 \\
0 & 16 & 7 & 23 & 14 & 6 & 22 & 13 & 4 & 15 & 12 & 3 & 19 & 5 & 21 & 18 & 9 & 20 & 11 & 2 & 24 & 10 & 1 & 17 & 8 \\
0 & 17 & 9 & 21 & 13 & 11 & 3 & 15 & 7 & 24 & 22 & 14 & 1 & 18 & 5 & 8 & 20 & 12 & 4 & 16 & 19 & 6 & 23 & 10 & 2 \\
0 & 18 & 6 & 24 & 12 & 16 & 9 & 22 & 10 & 3 & 7 & 20 & 13 & 1 & 19 & 23 & 11 & 4 & 17 & 5 & 14 & 2 & 15 & 8 & 21 \\
0 & 19 & 8 & 22 & 11 & 21 & 10 & 4 & 18 & 7 & 17 & 6 & 20 & 14 & 3 & 13 & 2 & 16 & 5 & 24 & 9 & 23 & 12 & 1 & 15 \\
0 & 20 & 15 & 10 & 5 & 3 & 23 & 18 & 13 & 8 & 1 & 21 & 16 & 11 & 6 & 4 & 24 & 19 & 14 & 9 & 2 & 22 & 17 & 12 & 7 \\
0 & 21 & 17 & 13 & 9 & 8 & 4 & 20 & 16 & 12 & 11 & 7 & 3 & 24 & 15 & 19 & 10 & 6 & 2 & 23 & 22 & 18 & 14 & 5 & 1 \\
0 & 22 & 19 & 11 & 8 & 13 & 5 & 2 & 24 & 16 & 21 & 18 & 10 & 7 & 4 & 9 & 1 & 23 & 15 & 12 & 17 & 14 & 6 & 3 & 20 \\
0 & 23 & 16 & 14 & 7 & 18 & 11 & 9 & 2 & 20 & 6 & 4 & 22 & 15 & 13 & 24 & 17 & 10 & 8 & 1 & 12 & 5 & 3 & 21 & 19 \\
0 & 24 & 18 & 12 & 6 & 23 & 17 & 11 & 5 & 4 & 16 & 10 & 9 & 3 & 22 & 14 & 8 & 2 & 21 & 15 & 7 & 1 & 20 & 19 & 13
\end{array}\right) $$

The python source code can be found [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJy9WFlv4zYQfjfg_6A6u4BoM06c7fYwqqcCBYrCbYEG6INhBJQlJ0QkWZHkjbSL_e-d4SFSlHwsdlEisaThcM6PwyOKd16eHEq_pg3NyXI88qDxnVcHwa36wlbE1aHIvKbtbwb7a0lRX349a8jbfOZLDTc3OW3wJydkmo9H41EE2lOeCfXnld9KSpyUcb_Tv65RlZImtVhKDonPaGiUXHm_7rNX1pQedPOMV3yftV27feH9ydOOLyDYL-PKL1j2GPtsGs4WhFx_Ep4J6VI8NQQaCoK0SLNIHvUnFDHm8cxTYiUpDA0pJJ8JerFNWFl69yxMtPPyF717eEAPHh7AwGRHC-MlNqTNi8ILlMCCOH25B325Q1wBLeLbyv_Ic_GvxFD1JHR9vRDGFmirom6IK_yfxbcSdPf1gkzEMB0iWJASsjR9Cn8M8OdhIro4NNFZY3rJJrgd7gwp63d2UWw0LU5qCE9pCAc1hB0N4TkN7JQGNqiBuTHtRVDIxjwoefPnuCl94rEs6qr_Lrh2zVNKOmxd4WjbGeHC_PPCBZvhcGqLTtIvgZwpADDUEZpvh7kXXQAtFgvyVg44zi0MOcuti91Rpqu84Fklat0aa7osKPJNz4o2XuCaVo8MIlwb4ursKuh-pVBAA69XF7tM_So3ELV-3RtgwhbXQiOYzaJIFgFdXAkdoEPNVXRZiTsjQkJca51ITliSPwFnXDEqVE-orONxfWSgjAn8Xn-K689D86MjHjKVTrAOUQZvTelITVIQlvCy8st9UcWRjywODwuRJ53n-9y_JafytX2Kt8_A_BsDoHe7Xp94EnvZvpJMA9HXg2WQw7_-8KXVA3EAZCnuwLsvDu6c0s0FPwtP8-kpBQ4PtOGxCKz6DPhs3uYCDOpW9aAY8d3OeoOUGtthhhFqXK7tTzH_jgBKN1bTsAGNnq0AxFDzGYKYM1Jae1CaiGZ12YCwoaw-NcBCtECkRnVbUYaH6TVlIPcD5dhRlsWvMHIyjEJsl80NszMQuNZbAxTr7A6wXQKpS6H0_0Do66Aj1nMBl_4a0lnQJaRwGRF0LCZOXxBUJ-aUSuorj-KizIvD9mlCPVUa8YAihFBHJK1OIF6BS9Q72Nn_ayR7j_HukEVxRhEjzyzLvIxvnypv_wxG82xw24C1zFWBu3N3R26WGgiy5XAdQRJ-z6r4MS78mkDkH3ml1qTcckPvUg6pv_bhaBOt-UYv-GQqn9MpFyjjBmVJnPl1RFoYuGa10MJokv4hqgViba-YLS6sWaLAKrJS8scsWNji-kc4S0nT4WuO8tWGimsgIiNltb9L9vvCT_aPEL8bfKioEGp6mm4PIbPFhTmgOYuqfZBauWhs_uY8fzd3InUzDNG0uTCLqZO_SJ_RhzL3rUPdObpLE2fKV3WIV443-o1oV4YxB1utlFVChG13ijldW1tvsUs0QVCyHXvFLvEck0aMvQccKBHupiI9vzlPe3EC1wpe--t1R5lxRh9DjeXtwVRXDZ3eoSgNasHJ98VaxqMcHHg_HmXwuBuPrBsBwGAm-My6VigbZEGuqboiMnc1eIejL1dWKx-O4TmFcrrVxruGY5-6Y7KWT2Vxoz5aI3IkgO40Lv2fSMcWXSX79iNV7aq1RWg2CYIVq_5GB3Ka6VKmVpr5fOKM7LOOR5ZUofCH6XRB6DsK6UamVpYQZgTdC_vf0btLmL6X8Vzd44WJuObxf6bvFO2upS3uWiKeMtbAT6F_g6QkYZU4oqjdPSjFnK9hCH1Pf9zYsc1VUJHyghTwGOJ4Z4NPBZy-WJNndd-a8kLtFStFVav7uUYycaY6dKlKQFwNEwC0vICb0K42KFrSqaWzA1MD37yZzES_n-Zkhp_W4IHNoxyW5n0TwLaK5wnfsoqfsuOcGekXmJH2zMD1TfynsJy9XC96d1cSqRhjvCoAjiDoeHOVpiwxXbaGK8iAOJPZCVA4fEFldMCgiTzF8ewDbJvipe0XSxJ_vUDopAJFqXhN14vlZnNMTgTn2IKystx_7MhqCxnY2NYeuzM81qkZtqcYsAnVGBkJRCig8IKVNKRbQvCcqr7b_pDQ9n179JoAoIHbXCF-acqKaIIoT0HbY5cFGIx2ekir8MW2Cr9tq47Jyo0suUQc91AvIUdlKbeEea1b6VykjsMc-aDc8k6PlyYt1fi8P556oprpegheYoUg_wEwvhq0&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

I have not proved anything yet, besides the addition being an abelian group.

It seems we get the finite fields of size $p^{(2^n)}$ ordered by inclusion.

Questions:
**1) Is there a more "direct"/"faster" way to define multiplication (such as in the case of addition)?
2) Does these definitions yield the fields $\operatorname{On}_p$?**

Thanks for your help!

Comment: related: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.0962.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a very simple definition, in the spirit of Conways recursive definition. I have no proof however that the two definitions are equivalent:

For $p>2$ a prime we first look at:

$\mathbf{F}_p$ and identify its elements with the $\{0,1,\cdots, p-1\}$. Addition and multipliaction is defined $\mod (p)$.
Induction step:
Let $k:=\mathbf{F}_{p^{(2^n)}}$ ($n=0,1,2, \cdots$).

Recursive definition of Addition:

$$x \oplus y := (x+y) \mod (p) + ( \lfloor \frac{x}{p} \rfloor \oplus \lfloor \frac{y}{p} \rfloor ) \cdot p$$

Recursive definition of Multiplication:

We make use of Conways $\operatorname{mex}$ function and define:

$m:=\operatorname{mex}( \{a^2| a \in k\})$

(Here we make use that the characteristic is not $p=2$ (For otherwise $a^2 = a$ ) )

Now we have a field extension $K:=k(m)$ of degree $2$ and the multiplication is defined recursively in terms of multiplications from $k$:

For $ a,b \le |K|-1 = p^{(2^{n+1})}-1$ we first compute division with remainder:

$$a = a_0 + a_1 q, b = b_0+b_1 q$$

and make use that $q \otimes q = m$, where $q$ is the natural number $q=p^{(2^n)}$:

$$a \otimes b := (a_0 \otimes b_0 \oplus a_1 \otimes b_1 \otimes m) + ( a_0 \otimes b_1 \oplus a_1 \otimes b_0 ) \cdot q$$

This defines a field extension of degree two and iterating this construction the set $\mathbb{N}_0$ becomes a quadratically closed field of characteristic $p$, since for each $x \in \mathbb{N}_0$ we can find by the $\operatorname{mex}$ construction a $y \in \mathbb{N}_0$ such that $y \otimes y = x$ in $\operatorname{On}_p$.